# removing path from url on redirect from previous site using .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

My situation is as follows, and I'm sorry if this seems simple enough:

- we have created a new site, and combined 9 previous domains to one site.
- my previous first sites URL was http://www.example.com
- the url example.com has been forwarded to my new site, with a page for each previous domain, eg: http://www.newsite.com/location/example
- on visiting a previous page on example.com, eg: http://www.example.com/oldpage/ , you get dropped onto http://www.newsite.com/location/example/oldpage/.
- I would like to get some assistance on getting a redirect or rewrite rule in my .htaccess file that will allow me to remove the /oldpage/ from the URL on my new site.

*I understand SEO practices, and practicality of this, I just need assistance in the .htaccess rule.*

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you're looking for?

```
RewriteRule ^location\/([\w-]+)\/([\w-]+)?\/?$ /location/$1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

It's hard to discern what you're trying to do from your question. Does the "location" part of the URL change?

Are you still showing the contents of `oldpage` at the new URL? Or are you wanting them to see the content at `https://www.newsite.com/location/example/` instead?

Comment: the /example/ part of my new url will change based on what site is was previously located at.  the content from the new page is just contact information, and not displaying any previuosly established content.  <br> what I want to do is remove the old page url from the end of the redirected landing page.  so if .com/location/example/old-page-url-to-be-removed/ is the url, i would like a rule that will just eliminate that /old-page-url-to-be-removed/ piece.

Answer (score 0):

i found my answer in the following: `RewriteRule ^location/example/. /location/example/ [R=301,L]`